# Event Dispatching System

Tags: c++, event-handling

Below you can see my implementation of a simple event dispatcher. I would like to get some feedback or improvement tips regarding the design and maybe an idea how to get rid of the static_cast. Thank you very much.

## Classes

**Event.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

enum class EventType : uint8_t {
    ButtonPress,
    FactoryReset
};

class Event {
    public:
        Event() = default;
        explicit Event(EventType type) : mType(type) {}
        virtual ~Event() = default;

        inline const EventType Type() const { return this->mType; };

    protected:
        EventType mType;
};
```

**ButtonPressEvent.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Event.h"

class ButtonPressEvent final : public Event {
    public:
        ButtonPressEvent(uint8_t pin) : Event(EventType::ButtonPress), mPin(pin) {};

        uint8_t mPin;
};
```

**FactoryResetEvent.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Event.h"

class FactoryResetEvent final : public Event {
    public:
        FactoryResetEvent() : Event(EventType::FactoryReset) {};
};
```

**Subscriber.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

#include "Event.h"

using EventHandlerType = std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<Event>&)>;

class Subscriber {
    public:
        virtual ~Subscriber() = default;
        virtual std::map<EventType, EventHandlerType> GetSubscribedEvents() = 0; 
};
```

**Dispatcher.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include "Event.h"
#include "Subscriber.h"

class Dispatcher {
    public:
        Dispatcher();

        void Listen(EventType type, const EventHandlerType &funct);
        void Subscribe(Subscriber *subscriber);
        void Post(std::unique_ptr<Event> &ptr);
        void Process();

    private:
        std::map<EventType, std::vector<EventHandlerType>> mObservers;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>> mEvents;
};
```

**Dispatcher.cpp**

```
#include "Dispatcher.h"

void Dispatcher::Listen(EventType type, const EventHandlerType &funct) {
    this->mObservers[type].push_back(funct);
}

void Dispatcher::Subscribe(Subscriber *subscriber) {
    for (auto&& event : subscriber->GetSubscribedEvents()) {
        this->Listen(event.first, event.second);
    }
}

void Dispatcher::Post(std::unique_ptr<Event> &ptr) {
    this->mEvents.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}

void Dispatcher::Process() {
    if (this->mEvents.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (auto&& event : this->mEvents) {
        // call listener functions
        for (auto&& observer : this->mObservers.at(event->Type())) {
            observer(event);
        }
    }

    this->mEvents.clear();
}
```

## Usage

**App.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Subscriber.h"

class App : public Subscriber {
    public:
        std::map<EventType, EventHandlerType> GetSubscribedEvents();
        void OnButtonPressEvent(std::unique_ptr<Event> &event);
};
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "App.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "ButtonPressEvent.h"

std::map<EventType, EventHandlerType> App::GetSubscribedEvents() {
    return {
        { EventType::ButtonPress, std::bind(&App::OnButtonPressEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1) }
    };
}

void App::OnButtonPressEvent(std::unique_ptr<Event> &event) {
    ButtonPressEvent *b = static_cast<ButtonPressEvent*>(event.get());

    printf("Button pin %d pressed", b->mPin);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Dispatcher.h"
#include "ButtonPressEvent.h"
#include "App.h"

void main(void) {
    App app;
    Dispatcher dispatcher;

    dispatcher.Subscribe(&app);

    // simulate event
    std::unique_ptr<Event> ptr(new ButtonPressEvent(11));
    dispatcher.Post(ptr);

    while (true) {
        dispatcher.Process();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Delete the default constructor of `Event`

The default constructor of `Event` doesn't initialize `mType`, leaving it in an undefined state. You probably never want to create a default initialized `Event` object, so it would be best to delete it to catch any incorrect use:

```
Event() = delete;
```

## Make `mType` `const`

Assuming you never want to change the type of an event after creating it, you should make the member variable `mType` `const`.

## Use `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map` where possible

Since you don't require `mObserver`s to be ordered in any way, use `std::unordered_map`, as it has \$O(1)\$ lookups instead of \$O(\log N)\$.

## Consider the overhead of returning a `std::map`

`GetSubscribedEvents()` is a very costly operation, since it returns a `std::map` by value. In this case, it is more efficient to let the subscriber call `Listen()` instead of the dispatcher. So instead of `GetSubscribedEvents()`, you could instead have a member function `Subscribe()` like so:

```
void App::Subscribe(Dispatcher& dispatcher) {
    dispatcher.Listen(EventType::ButtonPress,
                      std::bind(&App::OnButtonPressEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

And instead of:

```
dispatcher.Subscribe(&app);
```

Call:

```
app.Subscribe(dispatcher);
```

## Lifetime management of events

There are several issues with how you manage the lifetime of `Event` objects. It is a good idea to use `std::unique_ptr`, as this avoids memory management issues. However, you still need to consider how and when ownership is transferred. The function `Post()` takes a *reference* to a `std::unique_ptr<Event>`, and then internally `std::move()`s it into the vector `mEvents`. While this is legal, it is hard to see just from the API that `Post()` is taking over ownership. It is better to make this explicit, by having `Post()` take a forwarding reference:

```
void Dispatcher::Post(std::unique_ptr<Event>&& ptr) {
    mEvents.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}
```

This now forces the caller to use `std::move()` as well, which makes it clear at the call site that ownership is transferred:

```
std::unique_ptr<Event> ptr(new ButtonPressEvent(11));
dispatcher.Post(std::move(ptr));
```

While it looks like more work, it now actually supports passing in a temporary variable, like so:

```
dispatcher.Post(std::make_unique<ButtonPressEvent>(11));
```

In fact, since it is likely that you want to create and post the event in one go, you could make `Post()` a template that does this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Post(Args&&... args) {
    mEvents.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

And then the caller can do:

```
dispatcher.Post<ButtonPressEvent>(11);
```

Another lifetime issue happens when the observers are called. Again, you pass the event as a reference to a `std::unique_ptr<Event>`, since you defined the type of an observer as:

```
using EventHandlerType = std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<Event>&)>;
```

However, this allows an observer to modify the event, and even `std::move()` the event out of the `std::unique_ptr`. This is clearly very undesirable, as there might be multiple observers, and they all should see the same event. Instead, you should pass a `const` reference to the `Event`:

```
using EventHandlerType = std::function<void(const Event&)>;
```

Call the observers like so:

```
for (auto& event : mEvents)
    for (auto& observer : mObservers.at(event->Type()))
        observer(*event);
```

And then the observer looks like:

```
void App::OnButtonPressEvent(const Event& event) {
    auto& b = static_cast<const ButtonPressEvent&>(event);

    std::cout << "Button pin " << b.mPin << " pressed\n";
}
```

Comment: Amazing improvement. Thank you very much for the detailed feedback.
This will improve the code a lot.
Regarding the subscriber: I used to have it like the way you described. But then I thought it is better if the subscriber doesn't call the listen method directly. So the subscriber only knows about the events it subscribes and nothing about the dispatcher. But I didn't thought about the return type, so its still coupled to the dispatcher. So I will change it back to your proposal.
Any idea on how to get rid of the static_cast or do you think this isn't that bad?

Comment: I think it is possible to get rid of the `static_cast`, but that would require `Dispatcher` to know about all possible event types, either explicitly or by making `Dispatcher` a template and have each dispatcher instance deal with a single event type. It might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah, think you're right. I have one problem left:
If I change the `Post()` method to use template I get a `undefined reference to void Dispatcher::Post<ButtonPressEvent, int>(int&&)` when posting the event and I cannot find the mistake.

Comment: For template instantiation to work, the whole definition must be known at the point where it is instantiated. So move the implementation of `Dispatcher::Post()` into `class Dispatch` in `dispatcher.hpp`.

Comment: Thank you. Now everything works. On thing, in the `OnButtonPressedEvent` function a `const` is needed for the static_cast to work: `const ButtonPressEvent &b = ...`

Comment: Correct. I changed the code to use `auto`; it avoids these kinds of mistakes :)

Comment: One more issue: When posting an event without arguments `dispatcher.Post<FactoryResetEvent>();` the program crashes.

Comment: Solved it by adding: `template<typename T = void>
        inline void Post() {
            this->mEvents.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());
        }`

Comment: Another issue/question came up: If I collect the events and then process them async in the main loop I need a second `Process()` call to also handle the "response events" before I can sleep for a few seconds inside the main loop. If I would call the subscriber callbacks directly inside the post method all events and "subposted" events would be called and I can safley sleep for a few seconds. What do you think about this?

Comment: Once you go async you have to think about locking and wakeups. If done right you should be able to handle callbacks calling `Post()` themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Be consistent with the coding, currently there are differt strategies for creating default constructors in use.

## Prefer to include Header Files in cpp source files

By including header files in header files the code may become a maintenance problem and the size of the code that is compiled after the preprocessor runs may be unnecessary bloated. People who are maintaining code may not look at the header files when they are altering C++ source files. This may also reduce the number of files that need to compile when a header file changes.

## The this Object

Generally in C++ one does not need to use the `this` object to point to member variables or methods. The members can be accessed just by name. In `Dispatcer.cpp` there is no need to use `this`. It might have been necessary in the compiler you were using because the constructor wasn't defined. In the header file `FactorResetEvent.h` The constructor could be a default constructor as well.

```
#include "Dispatcher.h"

void Dispatcher::Listen(EventType type, const EventHandlerType& funct) {
    mObservers[type].push_back(funct);
}

void Dispatcher::Subscribe(Subscriber* subscriber) {
    for (auto&& event : subscriber->GetSubscribedEvents()) {
        Listen(event.first, event.second);
    }
}

void Dispatcher::Post(std::unique_ptr<Event>& ptr) {
    mEvents.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}

void Dispatcher::Process() {
    if (mEvents.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (auto&& event : mEvents) {
        // call listener functions
        for (auto&& observer : this->mObservers.at(event->Type())) {
            observer(event);
        }
    }

    mEvents.clear();
}
```

## Default Constructors

If you are not going to create a constructor for an object, such as the `Dispatcher` the constructor can be defined as a default constructor. In `Subscriber.h` the default destructor is used, but there is not constructor defined at all.

```
class Dispatcher {
public:
    Dispatcher() = default;

    void Listen(EventType type, const EventHandlerType& funct);
    void Subscribe(Subscriber* subscriber);
    void Post(std::unique_ptr<Event>& ptr);
    void Process();

private:
    std::map<EventType, std::vector<EventHandlerType>> mObservers;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>> mEvents;
};
```

My compiler and linker (Visual Studio 2019) reported that the constructor was undefined when I compiled the program.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.
Regarding the includes: Do you mean to use forward declarations instead for the types?
Regarding the "this" object: It's just my personal style. I like to use the this object.
I'll definitely rework my constructors.

Comment: If you are going to code in C++ professionally you need to stop using this. It is very uncommon. It possibly indicates your first programming language was PHP.